# Can I process a string which is like a json format using d3.json?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've searched online while most people are directly reading the .json file from url or local folder
like

```
 console.log("before csv ");
 d3.csv("cities.csv", function(data) {console.log(data)});
 console.log("before json");
 d3.json("flare.json",function(error,data2) {console.log(error, data2)});
```

while currently my requirement is that I have a string, which is in a json format, like

```
{"nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel"},
    {"id": "Napoleon"},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine"},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire"},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo"},
    {"id": "Geborand"},
    {"id": "Champtercier"},
    {"id": "Cravatte"},
    {"id": "Count"},
    {"id": "OldMan"},
    {"id": "Labarre"},
    {"id": "Valjean"},
    {"id": "Marguerite"},
    {"id": "Mme.deR"}
]}
```

is there a method I could directly process this string as the data read from .json or .csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 works with the JS objects only, d3.json is just a method to load the object from an external file. So if you dont need to load data from external file then dont use d3.json.

One of the way you can do like:

```
 var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `JSON.parse` function to parse the string to JSON without using d3 like this -

```
var json = JSON.parse(yourString);
```